# Real-time audio visualisation in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, audio, visualization

Are there any frameworks or open-source code that would simplify the process of implementing a real-time oscilloscope (time-domain audio visualisation) in OSX?

Ideally, I want to display a simple animated view representing the audio signal being input by the microphone input.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to use a QCView.  It's pretty easy to find QC compositions that display a bar graph display of the audio output.

Answer (score 2):

Look at a language called Pd (Pure Data).  It's the free version of Max/MSP.  It's the easiest way to do anything with audio.  One of the classes is in fact an oscilloscope.  Simply draw a line from the output of your sound source (it can be your mic, a sound file, or a live oscillator) to the oscilloscope and bathe in the visual output glory!

http://puredata.info/

Comment: Thanks but I need to integrate closely with a Cocoa application, and it needs to be non-GPL too. So not sure that's the answer

Comment: Ahh... as your thread title states perfectly!  I got too excited about plugging Pd and forgot to notice the details.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

the [SurfaceVertexProgram](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SurfaceVertexProgram/index.html) example is a nice demonstration of how to do an oscilloscope using OpenGL. the example is a bit out-dated (you have to build up a new xcode project), but functions and demonstrates very useful techniques.